# FB - Comment Moderation Tool bug or error in the code?

Tags: comments, facebook, open-graph

I am an admin of [this site](http://glamourina.pl/). This blog uses the FB comments plugin since around 1 year.

Since I enabled the July Breaking Changes, I: -am not receiving any more new comments notifications on FB; -New comments are not appearing in the Comments Moderation Tool -However everything in the blog seems to be working fine, people are commenting, admins can reply, etc.

This is the code in place:

```
<!--Facebook comments-->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.async=true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=184823298231084";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-num-posts="6" data-width="580"></div>
```

And these are the og tags for the post pages:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="617488311,100000919127291"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="184823298231084"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink() ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) ?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php single_post_title(''); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt($post->ID)); ?>" />
```

I hope you can take a look and are able to figure out where the problem is. I'd really appreciate your hints.

Do you see any error in the code I used?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786209/facebook-object-debugger-could-not-retrieve-data-from-url-200

Comment: Have you tried the plugin support forums? Would you mind adding a link to your question?

Comment: Vinod, Linter gives me only og:image should be larger: and Parser Mismatched Metadata: for 'fb:admins'. Kaiser, what link? The link of the site is there. Plugin support forums? This is not a wordpress plugin. This is facebook code inserted manually in the theme.

Comment: duplicate question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/100839/fb-comment-moderation-tool-bug